# How to use map to update data for a single column (Size) inside a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file named googleplaystore.csv. The file has a column called **Size**. The column has incorrect formatting ( Both MB and KB). I need to convert the numbers with Mb to Kb files. I wrote a custom function to change the formatting.

Here's the code I wrote for the custom function( to sort out the data which are in Mb):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)


inp0 = pd.read_csv("googleplaystore.csv")

sizeconvert = list(inp0.Size)
def change_size():
    for i in sizeconvert:
        a = [i][-1]
        if 'M' in i[-1]:
            b = a.replace('M'," ")
            float_kb = float(b)
            new = float_kb * 1000
            print (int(new))
        elif 'Varies with device' in i:
            c = a.replace('Varies with device', "0")
            print (int(c))
        else:
            print (a.replace('k', " "))




print (change_size())

inp0['Size'] = inp0.Size.map(change_size())
```

https://i.im.ge/2022/07/28/Fjef71.png. - The Size column does not get updated with the new values.

Using the above 'map' syntax does not update the DataFrame **Size** column. How do I update the column so that it shows the custom function output inside the DataFrame?

Comment: You do not need to use `map()` here. If you want to use `map()`, then the function `change_size` should be updated to handle just one row. Without using `map()`, you can rewrite the last line as `inp0['Size'] = change_size()` and make sure `change_size` returns the updated value.

Comment: @VishnuNadhan: I replaced the syntax with  inp0['Size'] = change_size() but now the Size column shows 'Size' as None for all the rows.

Comment: Is the function `change_size()` returning the modified Size? The code snippet you posted here does not return the updated value i.e. `new`

Comment: https://i.im.ge/2022/07/28/FmSMMM.png - It does show me the formatted updated list. @VishnuNadhan

Comment: Ok, if your goal is to update the Size column in the Dataframe, then in each if-case in `change_size`, you need to return the updated value.

Comment: Please upvote the comment if it has helped you resolve this issue. If no, feel free to raise questions or doubts here

Comment: @VishnuNadhan, I'm still stuck with this. I am unable to update the Size column in the Dataframe. What am I missing in the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the map syntax on a column, the argument to the function `change_size` will be a value of the column of a single row. An example here:

```
import pandas as pd

inp0 = pd.DataFrame({"Size": ["1.5M", "13k", "Varies with device"]}, columns=["Size"])


def change_size(num):
    if "M" in num:
        _num = num[:-1]
        float_kb = float(_num)
        new = float_kb * 1000
    elif "Varies with device" in num:
        _num = num.replace("Varies with device", "0")
        new = int(_num)
    elif "k" in num:
        # KB
        new = int(num[:-1])
    else:
        new = None
    return new


inp0["Size"] = inp0.Size.map(change_size)
print(inp0)
```

Output

```
     Size
0  1500.0
1    13.0
2     0.0
```